# C# WPF DataGrid improve performance

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, xaml, datagrid

In my WPF projects, I have a `TabControl` and every `TabItem` is a `UserControl`.

```
<TabControl Name="tc" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Header}" BorderThickness="0" Cursor="Arrow" Focusable="False" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type uc:MyUserControl}">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

On my code behind, I created a `ViewModelClass`. And the TabControl's `ItemsSource` is the `ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>`.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public MyUserControl Content { get; set; }
}
```

The `TabItem` header is binding to the `MyViewModel.Header` and the content is the `MyViewModel.MyUserControl`. My `UserControl` is actually a `DataGrid` with about 500 rows and 30 cols. Below is the code for the `DataGrid`.

```
    <DataGrid Name="DG" ReadOnly="true"
              CanUserResizeColumns="False"
              EnableRowVirtualization="True" 
              EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
              VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
              VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
              CanUserSortColumns="False"
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"/>
```

I know there are already some posts discussing the performance of WPF, but most of them are few years old and I already tried some of them e.g. EnableRowVirtualization, EnableColumnVirtualization, VirtualizingPanel.

And one of them is to set `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll` to `False`, when I do that the grid seems faster but switching the tab to the others. It takes much longer time. I think it's redrawing the `DataGrid`, so I give up this one.

Anyway the result is not really good, especially when the window is maximized, the performance of scrolling is really unacceptable.

And I don't think I am the only one facing this kind of problem. So I wanted to bring up this question again. Can anyone give me some suggestion to improve the `DataGrid` performance?

Comment: In most cases `UserControl` is a big overhead for display. Can you not use `UserControl` and just provide a `DataTemplate` or `ControlTemplate` instead?

Comment: 30 columns is a lot for a grid. The more columns you have, the more WPF has to render, which slows things down. We've faced exactly the same scenario, and the only answer was to reduce the number of columns. 30 is too much for usability anyway. Grids should show the just the most important properties, leaving the rest for details window.

Comment: Have you profiled your application to see what the potential bottlenecks are?